# Is there a way to get the progress info when download file/web page in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

the cpde below is to download web page from yahoo.com homepage

```
   var http = new XMLHttpRequest()
    var url = "http://yahoo.com:8080";
    var params = "";
    http.open("GET", url, true);

    // Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
                if (http.readyState == 4) {
                    if (http.status == 200) {
                        console.log("ok")
                    } else {
                        console.log("error: " + http.status)
                    }
                }
            }
    http.send(params);
```

Is there a way to get/display the progress info when download web page in XMLHttpRequest?

Your comment welcome

Comment: Use something like this `http.onprogress= callback`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http.onprogress= function(){
//event.loaded and event.total usage
}
```

Read more about `XMLHttpRequest` and `oprogress` here...[XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay in using jQuery Ajax, you can display a gif image(that will play by itself on the browser) just before the Ajax call, and when the ajax returns on success, you can remove the gif or the progress bar from your page(display: none using css).